# Windows Internet shortcut with embedded username:password

Tags: windows, web, url, shortcut

URLs of form http://username:password@example.com:80/ work fine in the address bar of any browser I tried, yet when I create a shortcut in Windows and try to launch it, it says it cannot find the address. How do I easily create shortcuts that log in automatically with a single click on the shortcut, and don't use any scripting? Note: please, no comments about how it's insecure to store passwords in plaintext inside the shortcut; I'm using this in a secure environment and the http connection is tunneled over SSH to a web service on a remote LAN (but that service is not configurable by me to simply not require a login).

Comment: What does the shortcut look like that you created?  Is it a text file or just a shortcut to that URL?

Answer (score 3):

it does work only up to internet explorer version 6.
It has been disabled from version 7 due to security reasons.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

Comment: My default browser is Firefox. However, the browser doesn't even launch when I try to open the shortcut--the error says that it's Windows that can't find that resource.